# what is the meaning of "being a screen" here? does it means that "the spiritualists should not allow them to present in their sacred ceremonies"?

Tags: meaning, interpretation

what is the meaning of "being a screen" here? does it means that "the spiritualists should not allow those villains to present in their sacred ceremonies"?

> These fraudulent rascals were sometimes mere cold-blooded swindlers,
>   and sometimes seem to have been real mediums whose psychic power had
>   for a time deserted them. There were scandals and exposures, some real
>   and some pretended. These exposures were then, as now, due often to
>   the Spiritualists themselves, who strongly objected to their sacred
>   ceremonies **being a screen** for the hypocrisies and blasphemies of those
>   villains who, like human hyenas, tried to make a fraudulent living out
>   of the dead.

source:http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html _ hos by acd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it means that villains were using spiritualist practices as a **screen** for their own malpractice.

Here **screen** has the same meaning as **blind** which [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/blind) gives as

> **blind**
>   NOUN
>   **2** Something designed to conceal one's real intentions.
>   *‘Ruse’ applies to that which is contrived as a blind for one's real intentions or for the truth.*

In other words they were pretending to be "real spiritualists", who objected to being impersonated in this way, and were as keen as anybody to expose them.